# Sorting a Table with VBA based on last two characters of each entry

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

In column ("E") is:

```
BDB1-1
BDB1-2
.
.
.
BDB1-9
BDB1-10
BDB1-11
```

I like to sort this column. If I do so with regular `Sort`, the code falsely lists the `BDB1-10` before the `BDB1-2` entry:

```
With Sheets("Probeninventar")
    .Range("A8:Z" & LastRow + 1).Sort key1:=.Range("E8"), order1:=xlAscending 
End With
```

How can I avoid this in a neat way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "Cheat" a little, add an helper column to the right of your range, where you add only the right 2 numbers as string, sort according to it, and at the end delete it.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddHelperColumn()

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

With Sheets("Probeninventar")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("AA8:AA" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "@" ' format the helper column as Text

    For i = 8 To LastRow
        If Int(Mid(.Range("E" & i).Value, InStr(.Range("E" & i).Value, "-") + 1)) < 10 Then
            .Range("AA" & i).Value2 = "0" & CStr(Mid(.Range("E" & i).Value, InStr(.Range("E" & i).Value, "-") + 1)) ' if less then 10, add `0` as prefix
        Else
            .Range("AA" & i).Value2 = CStr(Mid(.Range("E" & i).Value, InStr(.Range("E" & i).Value, "-") + 1))
        End If
    Next i

    .Range("A8:AA8" & LastRow + 1).Sort key1:=.Range("AA8"), order1:=xlAscending ' sort according to "helper" column
    .Columns(27).Delete ' delete the "helper" column
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Damn it. I was just posting! :-)

Comment: @QHarr sorry, you can be supportive ;) usually you beat me to it

Answer (score 2):

A possible way to face this problem is to split by `-` and sort the splited values. It is easier to be done with additional column than sorting a multidimensional array, received from the split by `-`. Thus, I have decided to show the easier part. Imagine that this is your input.

[image]

and the desired output looks like this:

[image]

Then this is the way to achieve it, if you split by `-` and sort by the splited value:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SortMe()

    Dim sortRange   As Range
    Dim sortNumbers As Variant
    Dim myCell As Range

    Set sortRange = Range("A1:A7")

    For Each myCell In sortRange
        myCell.Offset(0, 1) = Split(myCell, "-")(1)
    Next myCell

    Union(sortRange, sortRange.Offset(0, 1)).Sort Key1:=sortRange.Offset(0, 1)
    sortRange.Offset(0, 1).Clear

End Sub
```

As mentioned, it would be much faster to have a 2D array like this:

[image]

but then 95% of the answer would be "how to sort a 2D array".

---

And another way of sorting (without a second column) is with the usage of `System.Collections.ArrayList`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SortMe()

    Dim sortRange   As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim myList As Object
    Dim myListWhole As Object

    Set myList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set myListWhole = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set sortRange = Range("A1:A7")

    For Each myCell In sortRange
        myList.Add CLng((Split(myCell, "-")(UBound(Split(myCell, "-")))))
        myListWhole.Add myCell.Value2
    Next myCell

    myList.Sort

    Dim cnt As Long
    For Each myCell In sortRange
        Dim strVal As Variant
        For Each strVal In myListWhole
            If Split(strVal, "-")(UBound(Split(strVal, "-"))) = CStr(myList(0)) Then
                myCell = strVal
                myListWhole.Remove (strVal)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next strVal
        myList.RemoveAt 0
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I used `split` in the end, combined with the helper colum. I modified the `split` approach a little to ensure that the last characters of the entry after the "-" are used for sorting (in case there are several "-"). `For i = 8 To LastRow + 1
            WrdArray() = Split(.Range("F" & i).Value, "-")
            .Range("AA" & i).Value = WrdArray(UBound(WrdArray))
        Next` Thanks!

Comment: @Bendaua - welcome. Depending on the size of the input (if it is more than 1000), it would be probably much faster if you think about the `2D array` - thus it avoids writing sorting (2 times) and deleting. It simply writes once the sorted values.